# How do I take the input values from one screen to a gallery in another screen PowerApps?

Tags: excel, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am using PowerApps Canvas for the first time. I have created two screens. One has a gallery connected to an excel sheet. It displays the table contents from the excel file. And the second screen has some input text fields. I want to enter values in these fields and click on submit, so that when I go to the other screen I can see this new record in the gallery. I want to use the collect function for the submit button but it is showing problem with using `Record1` (name of the global variable in which I am storing the excel table). It says the specified data source cannot be used.

```
Collect(Record1,
  {
      AgentName:TextInput1.Text, 
      ID:TextInput4.Text, 
      Shift:TextInput2.Text, 
      Weekoff:TextInput3.Text
  }
)
```

I am setting Record1 as a global variable in the onStart property.

```
Set(Record1,Table1);
```

Edit: I ran `onStart` and the error is not there but new record isn't being displayed on the gallery. There is an error with setting the global variable `Unexpected Characters. The formula contains 'Ident' where 'Data' is expected`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making a global variable wasn't required. I just used the excel table directly in the other screen and the collect function works now.

Answer (score 0):

You want to store your input into your excel right? You need patch instead of collect. Collect is for local storage, patch creates an item in the datasource.